# MySQL Count if the value has not appeared before

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct-values

here is a table of `users, carts,` and `time`.
A `user` can have **multiple** `carts`. All **anonymous** `user`s have the `userId = 1000`; any **identified user** has an ID different from `1000`.

All `cartId`s are unique.

```
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| userId     | cartId      | time                 | 
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 7650       | 231         | 2014-08-27 13:41:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 7632       | 221         | 2014-08-27 13:42:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 7650       | 289         | 2014-08-27 14:13:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 1000       | 321         | 2014-08-27 14:41:02  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 7650       | 500         | 2014-08-27 17:41:02  |
```

I am interested in **calculating the number of distinct identified users by the hour of the day**.

I tried the following, but it cannot keep a record of all the IDs entered before when I group by them up by Hour(Date).

```
COUNT( distinct (case when userId <> 1000 then userId end)) as numSELFIDUsers
```

For the output, I want something like:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| Date       | HourOfDay   | numSELFIDUsers       | 
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 2014-08-27 | 13          |  2                   |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 2014-08-27 | 14          |  0                   |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| 2014-08-27 | 17          |  0                   |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Please let me know if there are any questions.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
select date(time), hour(time),
       COUNT(distinct case when userId <> 1000 then userId end) as numSELFIDUsers
from usercarts
where date(time) = '2014-08-27'
group by date(time), hour(time)
order by 1, 2;
```

This looks similar to what you have in the query.  I'm not sure why your version wouldn't work.

EDIT:

You also seem to want times with 0 counts.  This is a bit more challenging, but you can do it like this:

```
select d.dt, h.hr, COUNT(distinct case when userId <> 1000 then userId end) 
from (select distinct date(time) dt from usercarts where dt IN YOUR RANGE) d cross join
     (select 0 as hr union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all . . .
      select 23
     ) h left join
     usercart uc
     on date(uc.time) = d.dt and hour(uc.time) = h.hr;
```

The `. . .` is where you put in the rest of the numbers from 3 to 23.

EDIT II:

I suspect that you are actually looking for the first time a user appears.  If so, try this:

```
select date(firsttime), hour(firsttime), count(*) as NumFirstUsers
from (select userId, min(time) as firsttime
      from usercarts
      where userid <> 1000
      group by userId
     ) u
group by date(firsttime), hour(firsttime)
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: I am not sure the code solves the problem. What I am trying to do is count the number of distinct self-id users by the hour of the day. My code doesn't work because I am grouping them by the hour(date); hence, a RETURNING user (say 7650 in my example) is counted again as a self-id user. I don't want it to count that since the user has had her first cart done earlier. 

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @eager_learner313 . . . EDIT II should count them correctly.  To phrase it differently, you want to count them the first time they appear.